# Even though versus Even so

Tags: conjunctions

I cannot understand why we cannot use "even though" instead of "even so" or vice versa.

For example :

> I know her English isn't very good, but even so I can understand her.
>   ( [original sentence](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv122.shtml))

If we can rewrite it with "even though", does it mean different thing?

> Even though her English isn't very good, I can understand her. (my sentence)

Some other examples:

> The evidence was only circumstantial. Even so, he was convicted and
>   spent ten years in prison for a crime that he perhaps did not commit. (original)
>
> Even though the evidence was only circumstantial, he was convicted and
>   spent ten years in prison for a crime that he perhaps did not commit.
>
> She is loud and unfriendly. Even so, I like her. (original)
>
> Even though she is loud and unfriendly, I like her.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems based on the false hypothesis that we cannot say things that we do say. The two approaches are grammatical, commonly used, and essentially synonymous.

Comment: I suspect that you have heard that simply **replacing** one by the other, without reordering things, is not done. E.g.: *Even though, I like her* or *Even so she is loud, I like her.* That's a different story.

Comment: @Drew sorry I could not understand your example(Even though, I like her or Even so she is loud, I like her. That's a different story).

Comment: My comment was repeated by @DaniilAgashiyev: the two phrases are not interchangeable. In the examples you gave, there is no problem - the alternatives you give are equivalent and commonly used. But you cannot just interchange the two in all contexts (e.g. in the examples I gave).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Even so*** and ***even though*** are not interchangeable within a given sentence.  They are both used to present a counterpoint to a fact or a statement, but the key difference is that ***even though*** precedes the fact, while ***even so*** follows it.

***Even so***, in context, translates as "[*insert fact or statement*]...***even with that fact...***" You can also replace it with ***nevertheless*** or ***still***.

On the other hand, ***Even though*** means "***despite the fact that*** [*insert fact or statement*]"

Naturally though, you can restructure a sentence to make you use of either to convey the same meaning, as your examples illustrate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Can I say that you say that the sentences have  different structures but the both sentences ( the original one and mine ) have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that.